# Polars - Windows function with condition

Tags: python-polars

Given this DataFrame.

```
example_df = pl.DataFrame(
    {'id':['1']*3 + ['2']*3,
     'actions': [0,1,2, 0, 1, 2],
     'campaign_name': [None,None, '2', '1', '2', None] ,
     'event_time': [1,2,3,0,1,2],
     'session_id':['session_1']*6}
)

id  actions campaign_name   event_time  session_id
str  i64           str          i64        str
"1"   0           null           1      "session_1"
"1"   1           null           2      "session_1"
"1"   2           "2"            3      "session_1"
"2"   0           "1"            0      "session_1"
"2"   1           "2"            1      "session_1"
"2"   2           null           2      "session_1"
```

I want to get the min\max `event_time` by combination group of session_id and id under condition `campaign_name`.

Here is my code.

```
example_df.with_columns(
        
 
       pl.when(pl.col('campaign_name').is_in(['1','2']))
        .then(
            pl.col('actions').min().over(['session_id', 'id']).alias('min_action')
        ),
        pl.when(pl.col('campaign_name').is_in(['1','2']))
        .then(
            pl.col('actions').max().over(['session_id', 'id']).alias('max_action')
        )  
    )
```

But the results are not as expected.

The code works in the opposite direction.

The code calculates the min/max on all the values instead on the values filtered by the condition.

Expected results:

```
id  actions campaign_name   event_time  session_id  min_action  max_action
str  i64        str             i64         str        i64         i64
"1"   0        null              1      "session_1"     2           2
"1"   1        null              2      "session_1"     2           2
"1"   2        "2"               3      "session_1"     2           2
"2"   0        "1"               0      "session_1"     0           1
"2"   1        "2"               1      "session_1"     0           1
"2"   2        null              2      "session_1"     0           1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when` is a bit odd to think about in this way - it determines what expression is being run per row, but that expression in `then` is not restricted in any way by the `when`.

You want a `filter` directly and no `when`:

```py
example_df.with_columns(
    pl.col('actions').filter(pl.col('campaign_name').is_in(['1','2'])).min().over(['session_id', 'id']).alias('min_action'),
    pl.col('actions').filter(pl.col('campaign_name').is_in(['1','2'])).max().over(['session_id', 'id']).alias('max_action'),
)
```